# HDD4780 LCD displaying Hex Character not working [Python]

Tags: python, hex, character, lcd

I want to display an up and down arrow on my LCD. I checked the char set and it says that the up arrow is 00011000 and the down arrow 00011001 so they have the hex values 18 and 19. But using

```
lcd.message("\x18")
```

doesn't work. It works with the degree symbol (\xDF) though. I can't figure out the problem. Do you guys have any idea of what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using ROM code A00 and not ROM code A02.
Please take a look here:
http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.06/11.13/44780.pdf
(page 17-18).

[image]